# Best effort traffic and real time traffic difference

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

What is the difference between **Best effort traffic** and **Real time traffic**? Is TCP means best effort traffic and UDP means real time traffic? Or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between Best effort traffic and Real time
>   traffic?

A [Wikipedia description on Traffic classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_classification) gives the difference as :-

**Sensitive traffic/Real time traffic***

Sensitive traffic is traffic the operator has an expectation to deliver on time. This includes VoIP, online gaming, video conferencing, and web browsing. Traffic management schemes are typically tailored in such a way that the quality of service of these selected uses is guaranteed, or at least prioritized over other classes of traffic. This can be accomplished by the absence of shaping for this traffic class, or by prioritizing sensitive traffic above other classes.

**Best-effort traffic**

Best effort traffic is all other kinds of non-detrimental traffic. This is traffic that the ISP deems isn't sensitive to Quality of Service metrics (jitter, packet loss, latency). A typical example would be peer-to-peer and email applications. Traffic management schemes are generally tailored so best-effort traffic gets what is left after sensitive traffic.

> Is TCP means best effort traffic and UDP means real time traffic?

No, those are transport layer protocols and are so broad topic on which books can be written. A web-search would suffice to clear the difference between TCP & UDP.

---

* ***NOTE*** : It is not mentioned in the Wikipedia about real time traffic, but, it can be safely assumed that sensitive traffic is what a real time traffic can be equated to as the latter are very sensitive/ .

Comment: TCP and UDP are not network layer protocols. They are transport layer protocols.

Comment: @rodolk - Thanks, that was a mistype. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to clarify some concepts here. Best-effort traffic and real-time traffic have no relation at all.

Best effort tells you "I'll do whatever I can to make your datagram (or packet) reach the destination but I cannot assure you 100% it will reach there". The concept of best effort is not related to TCP or UDP but to IP. While TCP and UDP are transport layer protocols, IP is a network layer protocol.

We say IP is a best-effort protocol. The reason is that IP is the protocol, at network layer, responsible for routing a datagram from a NIC (A Network Interface Card with an IP address associated) in a node to a destination NIC at another, destination, machine (with other IP address) through different networks (or within the same network). It will take the datagram from one node's NIC to another's node NIC. However, the datagram could be dropped in the middle by a router in case of congestion. This is why we say IP is a best-effort protocol.

Real-time traffic is a concept orthogonal to best-effort. It refers to traffic that has to meet certain time constraints more related to the application than to the protocol itself. For example, in video applications it is usually required to show a minimum of 30 Frames per Second (FPS) to deliver a good experience, so the traffic needs to be fast enough to convey a minimum of 30 frames per second from the server to the client. Another important concept in real-time traffic is jitter, some applications need a uniform transmission rate more than very high speed, this is the case for VoIP for example. Real-time protocols usually use UDP to transmit real-time data. Remember UDP is a Transport Layer Protocol (layer 4). The reason is that UDP is lightweight and real-time applications like VoIP or video don't care if a datagram is lost in the middle, they care more about speed and jitter and don't want to waste time resending lost datagrams. Example: RTP (Real-time protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)

TCP is a reliable and connection oriented protocol that is useful for example for web browsing. It assures a message will be transmitted from one process running in a node to another process in another node. UDP is connectionless and non-reliable. Video and voice applications don't need this reliability provided by TCP.

But don't get confused between unreliable and best-effort. UDP is unreliable because it doesn't assure you that a UDP datagram will reach the destination. IP is best effort.